# automatically filling directories while typing

Tags: windows, visual-c++, search, unmanaged

I am writing an application in VC++(unmanaged) which is going to run in xp and above PC's. I need to add an functionality which will allow the user to see the directories being suggested as the user types the path in a stext box. This is similar to the behaviour of the run dialog in vista/7.

Thanks in advance,
John.

Comment: I am contemplating on lucene. But i want to make sure there is no methods provided by windows to acheive the same in a easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SHAutoComplete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759862%28VS.85%29.aspx)